# Cannot Start Elastic Search on Ubuntu 17

Tags: linux, ubuntu, elasticsearch

I installed the Elastic Search by downloading the `.deb` package from [this](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch) link.
After installing I tried to browse to `http://localhost:9200/` where I'm getting **connection refused error**, so I checked the status of elastic search service by running the following command `sudo service elasticsearch status` and I'm getting the below logs :

```
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-08-04 18:15:59 IST; 3s ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
  Process: 23168 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --
  Process: 23163 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-systemd-pre-exec (code=exited, 
 Main PID: 23168 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 04 18:15:59 mrrobot-Inspiron-N5110 systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
Aug 04 18:15:59 mrrobot-Inspiron-N5110 systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
Aug 04 18:15:59 mrrobot-Inspiron-N5110 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exit
Aug 04 18:15:59 mrrobot-Inspiron-N5110 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 04 18:15:59 mrrobot-Inspiron-N5110 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
lines 1-13/13 (END)
```

Can some one tell me how to start the service?

Comment: We need logs! Usually you find it in /var/lib/elasticsearch.

Comment: @MartinSchulze I tried to fetch the logs however, the directory at the location /var/lib/elasticsearch is empty.

Comment: please run it using  bin/elasticsearch

Comment: There's nothing inside bin with named elasticsearch or something close to that. There's a directory named elasticsearch under etc/elasticsearch and contains following : elasticsearch.yml , jvm.options , log4j2.properties , scripts

Comment: /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch this should be right

Comment: under this /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin, I only have following files :
elasticsearch    ,    elasticsearch-keystore  , elasticsearch-systemd-pre-exec
elasticsearch.in.sh ,  elasticsearch-plugin  ,  elasticsearch-translog

Comment: can you run `journalctl -f` when you try to start ES, is anything in the output?

Comment: I managed to run it after reinstalling both java and elastic search.